# Why previously selected request.getParameter is going null, when 2nd dropdown list box populating in same jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp

Following is my `jsp` page, where I am Searching Voucher Period in Oracle table
through servlet :-  `v_p_Search1.java`, Which is working properly, Searched Result
Populating and displaying into `ArrayList` at `jsp` page. And I am Selecting a Specific Voucher Period from drop down Select Box. And Storing the Selected Voucher Period through the Following statement :-
`type="text" name="voucherperiod" value="<%=request.getParameter("database1")%>"`

Later I am searching Branch Code in Oracle table through servlet :- `b_c_Search1.java`, Which is also working properly, Searched Result Populating and displaying into `ArrayList` at same `jsp` page. And I am Selecting Multiple Branch Code from `Listbox`. And Storing the Selected Multiple Branch Code in another `ArrayList` through :- `ar.add(clrs[i]);`

But problem is that, when 2nd dropdown listbox populating in same `jsp` page,
the previous selected request.getParameter :-
`type="text" name="voucherperiod" value="<%=request.getParameter("database1")%>"`
is going null. 
My requirement is to pass both the Parameter [selected voucher period] and 
[selected multiple Branch Code] from `branch_voucher.jsp` to servlet :- `b_c_Detail_Search.java` for further Processing.

```
branch_voucher.jsp
===================

<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>VOUCHER PERIOD AND BRANCH CODE SELECTION</TITLE>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <H1><center><color : blue>VOUCHER PERIOD AND BRANCH CODE SELECTION</center></H1>

            <FORM NAME="form1" ACTION="branch_voucher.jsp" METHOD="GET">
            <label1> Click To </label1> 
            <input type="submit" value="Generate Voucher Period List" onclick="form.action='v_p_Search1';">
            <label1 for="name">Voucher Period</label1>  
            <td>
            <select name="database1">
            <option value="" selected>select</option>
            <%
               if (request.getAttribute("vpList") != null) {
                   ArrayList vlist = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("vpList");
                   for(int i=0;i<vlist.size();i++) {
                   String VField=vlist.get(i).toString();
            %>
             <option value="<%=VField %>"><%=VField %></option>
            <%
                    }
                }

            %>
            </FORM>    
            </select>
            </td>
            <label1> And Click To </label1> 
            <input type="submit" value="Accept">
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>Voucher Period Selected</td>
            <td> :- </td>
            <%if(request.getParameter("database1")!=null){ %>
            <td><input type="text" name="voucherperiod" value="<%=request.getParameter("database1")%>"></input>
            <%}
            %>                                    
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>

            <FORM NAME="form1" ACTION="branch_voucher.jsp" METHOD="GET">
            <br />
            <br />
            <label1> Click To </label1> 
            <input type="submit" value="Generate Branch Code List" onclick="form.action='b_c_Search1';">
            <br />
            <label1 for="name">Branch Code List</label1>
            <table border="1">
            <tr><td></td>
            <br />
            </tr>
            <select name="fstname" multiple size="10">
            <%
               if (request.getAttribute("BCList") != null) {
                   ArrayList list = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("BCList");
                   for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
                   String Field=list.get(i).toString();
                   int p=0;
            %>
                 <option value="<%=Field %>"><%=Field %> </option>
            <%
                       p++;
                                                  }
                                                           }
            %>
            </FORM>   
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            </select>
            <br>
            <label1> And Click To </label1> 
            <input type="submit" value="Accept"><br/>
            <%
                      String clrs[] = request.getParameterValues("fstname");
              ArrayList ar=new ArrayList();
                      if(clrs != null){
            %>
                 <p><b>You have selected the following Branchs</b></p>
            <%
                  for(int i=0; i<clrs.length; i++){
                   ar.add(clrs[i]);
            %>
                     <li><%=clrs[i]%></li>
            <%
                                                  }
            %>
            <%
                                      }
                session.setAttribute("ARlistName",ar); 
            %>

            <FORM NAME="form1" ACTION="branch_voucher.jsp" METHOD="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="Search Branch Code Detail" onclick="form.action='b_c_Detail_Search';">
            <%
            %>
            </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>



    b_c_Detail_Search.java
    ======================


    import java.io.*;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.sql.*;
    import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;
    import oracle.sql.*;
    import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;


    public class b_c_Detail_Search extends HttpServlet {
      public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                     throws ServletException, IOException  {


       PrintWriter pwinsert = response.getWriter();
       response.setContentType("text/html");
       PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String Field_br_cd = " ";
    String kk = " ";
    String Field_br_nm = " ";
    String v_p_Field=" ";


             String v_p_Field_a = request.getParameter("voucherperiod"); 
             ArrayList ar=ArrayList)request.getSession().getAttribute("ARlistName"); 

          String title = "Using GET Method to Read Form Data";
          String docType =
          "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
          "transitional//en\">\n";
          out.println(docType +
                    "<html>\n" +
                    "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
                    "<body bgcolor=\"#f0f0f0\">\n" +
                    "<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n" +
                    "<ul>\n" +
                    "</body></html>");
                       out.println("<html>"); 
                       out.println("<head>"); 
                       out.println("<title>Voucher Period Selected</title>"); 
                       out.println("</head>");
                       int b = 2; 
                       out.println("<center><table border="+b+ "> "); 
                       out.println("<tr>");                
                       out.println("<td>"+ v_p_Field_a +"</td>"); 
                       out.println("</tr>");
                       out.println("<html>"); 
                       out.println("<head>"); 
                       out.println("<title>List Of Branch Code Selected</title>"); 
                       out.println("</head>"); 
                       int a = 2; 
                       out.println("<center><table border="+a+ "> "); 
                       out.println("<tr>");

                       for(int i=0;i<ar.size();i++) {
                       String Field=ar.get(i).toString();
                       Field_br_cd = Field.substring(0, 5);
                       out.println("<td>"+ Field_br_cd +"</td>"); 
                       Field_br_nm = " ";
                       kk = " ";
                           for (int j=7;j<Field.length();j++)
                               {
                            char k = Field.charAt(j);
                            kk = kk + Character.toString(k);
                                                Field_br_nm=kk;
                               } 
                        out.println("<td>"+ Field_br_nm +"</td>"); 
                        out.println("</tr>"); 


                                                    }
            }

    }
```

Comment: Only one `<form>...</form>` is submiting its inputs as request parameters. By the way it of course is `</select></form>` - not the other way around. Make one large form.

Comment: My observation is that, due to Submit Button 3rd and 4th  selected voucher period going null. 
If I can replace Submit Button 3rd and 4th  may be the problem will be solved. But I don’t know 
How Step 4 and Step 5 will perform same without using two Submit Button.